# Como percorrer uma lista de objetos em javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase

[image: Array de Objeto na imagem]
Bom, eu recuperei esse valor do meu nó de usuarios do firebase, porem não estou sabendo recuperar os valores, por exemplo: nome, celular, email.

Obs: Já tentei this.obj[0].nome;
e me retorna undefined.

Comment: Sua pergunta está estranha, pelo que dá pra entender na pergunta, a questão tem mais a ver com `javascript` e em como utilizar os objetos: [veja mais](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/JavaScript/Objetos/B%C3%A1sico)

Comment: Bom pela sua pergunta, da para ver que não tem conhecimento da linguagem Javascript, isso não é um objeto é um **array** de objeto. Vc terá que percorrer o  array para pegar os valores contidos no objeto, pode fazer utilizando métodos Javascript como um simples **for**, **forEach** ou **map** por exemplo.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado, realmente comecei a conhecer o javascript agora, desculpem pela pergunta confusa, e muito obrigado pelas dica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem diversas formas depende do que você quer? como informação se você quer filtar por algum valor se você quer multiplicar.

os primeiros casos são

```
const clients = [
  { id: 1, nome: 'Luas 1' },
  { id: 2, nome: 'Luas 2' },
  { id: 3, nome: 'Luas 3' }
];

// Essa forma você pega os clientes pelo objeto de cada
clients.forEach(item => {
   console.log(item.id, item.nome);
});

// Essa forma você pega os clientes por chave
for (key in clients) {
   console.log(clients[key]);
}
```

Veja na documentação do mozila tem todos os protótipos que podem ser usados em um array basta ler alguns minutinhos.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Comment: Muito obrigado Artsher,  porém eu ainda recebo undefined.

Comment: e por que você tem que fazer o laço na chave. no seu caso vai ser ['VALORDATA']

Comment: Show de bola!!!